# How do I install Oracle Enterprise Repository 12c on Macbook?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, oracle-fusion-middleware, soa-suite

I am trying to install the Oracle SOA stack of products on my MacBook but I am stuck at one very crucial point. Need a database on my machine for OER but cannot figure out what to do?

**Here is what I have already done:**

- Successfully installed [Oracle SOA Suite 12c](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/downloads/index.html)
- I have downloaded [OER](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/repository/downloads/index.html)
- I have tried installing [Oracle Database 12c](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html), with Linux version even though as there is no download choice for Mac. I faced following error : `./runInstaller: line 252: /Users/madhu/Oracle/product/18.0.0/dbhome_1/install/.oui: cannot execute binary file`
- I checked supported database for OER but did not find MySQL or SQLlite or any other product than Oracle and Microsoft SQL server.
- Microsoft SQL server is obviously not supported in MacOS

So at the as for OER a database is essential and I cannot install any supported database on MacBook.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Even if the installer script doesn't instantly fail, that doesn't mean that the Linux version of ODB 12c will magically work on OS X.

Install ODB or SQL Server on something else and configure OER to connect to it. That "something else" can be a virtual machine running on your Mac.

- Install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) (or your preferred hypervisor);
- Install Linux or Windows on a virtual machine;
- Install and configure Oracle Database or SQL Server on that VM;
- Consult the manual to configure networking for your virtual machine so the database is accessible from your host machine.

Answer (score 1):

WebLogic will run on the Mac but FMW/SOA will not - at least not stable. Neither will the database. 
& I know I teach/install/admin these products and am a certified Oracle trainer. I’ve tried...my time was worth more than it took to try and get it to work outside a vm-natively. I assume yours is too.

Unless you are actively trying to learn how to install them, then yes #backgammon is right, install them in a VM.
BUT, if you just want to use them and are not as interested in installation, then use one of the prebuilt -preconfigured FMW virtual box images [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html#soa12) that will run on the Mac under virtual box.
Then Install OER in that image.
But, be advised OER is no longer sold by Oracle, even though it’s available for download.
It has been replaced by the API cloud service product.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.